# Source for Striking Self during Viduy

Tags: minhag, sources-mekorot, provenance, parts-of-the-body, viduy-confession

What is the earliest source for striking one's chest while reciting Vidduy?

Comment: There is a mention of striking with a fist in Isaiah 58:4 but I don't think that refers to striking yourself in vidui, more that the people had violence on their mind even when fasting.

Comment: Rabbi Arthur Scroll doesn't bring down a source in the Machzor?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[The Encyclopedia of Jewish Prayer: The Ashkenazic and Sephardic Rites](https://books.google.nl/books?id=pbuPJeQyeskC&pg=PA39&lpg=PA39&dq=vidui+heart&source=bl&ots=qa1TQh4U3U&sig=24aIvTYtmqqmQ5uIxatgIFGXKYQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CE8Q6AEwCGoVChMI8q7NvJvixgIVBc9yCh2J9gLQ#v=onepage&q=vidui%20heart&f=false) (Macy Nulman) has the following on the beating of the heart during Viduy

> When saying Ashamnu we stand somewhat bent over, without leaning on
>   any kind of support, just as in reciting Modim (MB, 607:10 ; Magen
>   Avraham 607:4), a position of abject humility and contrition. One
>   should beat upon his breast or heart with the fist at the mention of
>   sin (Matt Eph 621:16). This practice is based on the verse vehahai
>   yiten el libo, "And the living will lay it to his heart.". Rabbi Manna
>   said, “Why does one beat the heart [in remorse for one’s sins]? This
>   is to indicate that all [evil] comes from there “(Midrash Rabbah on
>   Kohelet 7:2). Similarly, the Talmud states, “The heart and eyes are
>   two agents of sin; the eye sees, the heart desires, and the
>   instruments of action, that is, the hands, complete”. Hence, the hand
>   beats the heart as if to denote that the heart caused wrongdoing (Jer.
>   Ber. 36).