# Tapping chest in סלח לנו

Tags: shemoneh-esrei

Artscroll siddur says to tap ones chest during the beracha of סלח לנו in the עמידה. **Where does this come from?**

There didn't seem to a part of שולחן ערוך that talks about this ברכה and other סידורים don't mention it....

Comment: Dunno who discusses touching the chest, but the chapter in at least טור and I assume (I hadn't checked) שלחן ערוך is 115.

Comment: @msh210 I saw the bracha discussed in טור, not שולחן ערוך

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Source for Striking Self during Viduy](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/60498/source-for-striking-self-during-viduy)

Comment: @mevaqesh Why do you assume the minhag for Slach Lanu and Vidui came from the same place? They're certainly related, but they could very well be different.

Comment: סלח לנו is a confession, which is what ודוי means.@DonielF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rav Ari Enkin [writes](http://halachafortodaycom.blogspot.com/2012/04/q-page-2.html?m=1):

> "The Mishna Berura comments that our sins and misdeeds should be at
>   the forefront of our hearts and minds when we recite the "slach lanu"
>   blessing in shemoneh esrei.[Mishna Berura 115:1] This is the source for the custom to
>   beat one's chest when reciting the words "chatanu" and "pashanu" in
>   the course of this blessing.[Piskei Teshuvot 115:2] There is also a Midrash which teaches
>   that whenever one recalls one’s sins, one should pound one’s chest.[Kohelet Rabba 7:2]
>   This is because banging on one's chest symbolizes that forbidden
>   desires originate in one's heart. It might also be that banging on
>   one's chest during slach lanu is something that was adopted from the
>   Yom Kippur custom to do so when reciting "chatanu" and "pashanu" in
>   the course of the prayers.[Magen Avraham 607:3]"

Comment: I'll check the sources